# Use of undeclared identifier 'RTLD_SELF'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have just started iPad programming. I am trying to import an existing project. I am getting the following error, while building through Xcode(4.2): Google didn't help.

[image]

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2009 Facebook
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
*/ 

#import "FBLoginButton.h"
#import "FBLoginDialog.h"

#include <dlfcn.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static UIAccessibilityTraits *traitImage = nil, *traitButton = nil;

@implementation FBLoginButton

@synthesize session = _session, style = _style;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// private

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [FBLoginButton class]) {
        // Try to load the accessibility trait values on OS 3.0
        traitImage = dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "UIAccessibilityTraitImage");
        traitButton = dlsym(RTLD_SELF, "UIAccessibilityTraitButton");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing some files it looks like. With another 'clue' being the warning in the line right above - `Implicit declaration of function dlsym is invalid in C99`. I would guess one of the header files is missing from this import.

Comment: These are the header files: `#import "FBLoginButton.h"
#import "FBLoginDialog.h"

#import <dlfcn.h>
`

Comment: Odd, works for me. Check `/usr/include` and verify that `dlfcn.h` is present on your system.

Comment: @Perception Ya got it, I was searching in `/Developer/usr/include` and through finder/spotlight thats why couldn't find it.

Comment: Now how should I go about finding the bug? Is there something missing in this file?

Comment: Are you running with custom include flags? Please post the beginning of your file with all the imports.

Comment: @Perception Added in the original post.

Comment: @Ava so you still have the same warning? Is the header file under the right platform and sdk?

Comment: @fbernardo Yes, it is an error not a warning.

Comment: @Ava in your screenshot you have both. Well... RTLD_SELF should be defined in iOS. Try with RTLD_DEFAULT just to see if it works.

Comment: Actually the warning opens up with an error and a warning. Doesn't work with RTLD_DEFAULT either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both errors were fixed by enclosing the the method in:

```
#ifdef RTLD_SELF

      //initialize method

#endif
```

Got hint from http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-45.1/unit-tests/test-cases/dlsym-RTLD_SELF/main.c?txt